# How to read data from file using pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following `pgfplots` example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{datax.dat}
1,3,6
2,4,5
3,3,7
4,1,2
5,1,1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$x$},ylabel={Column Data}]

% Graph column 2 versus column 0
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=2,col sep=comma] {datax.dat};
\addlegendentry{Column 3}% y index+1 since humans count from 1

% Graph column 1 versus column 0    
\addplot table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma] {datax.dat};
\addlegendentry{Column 2}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to read the data defined in `datax.dat` from file `test.txt` that is found in the same directory where the tex document itself. Could you please help me how to perform this?

Comment: Do you want to read it so as to plot it?  Or do you want to read it to typeset it?  Or do you want to read it and use it as a parameter inside of a macro?

Comment: I would like to plot it. Does it work if I put the rows between `\begin{filecontents}` and `\end{filecontents}` into a separate file, called `test.tex` and read this file with `\input{test.tex}`?

Comment: The `filecontents` is just a LaTeX way of creating an external text file from within LaTeX.  If you already have data in a file `test.tex`, you could omit the `filecontents` block and just change the name of the `\addplot` argument from `datax,dat` to `test.tex`, assuming the format is the same.